# ICMP rate-limit on time-exceeded messages

Tags: cisco, router, icmp, rate-limiting

How can I set ICMP rate-limiting in a Cisco router? 
[**Here**](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_4t/12_4t2/hticmpun.html#wp1063341) on the manual page they only talk about ICMP unreachable messages:

```
ip icmp rate-limit unreachable [df] [ms] [log [packets] [interval-ms]]
```

Is there anything that also includes other ICMP message types? For instance, what if I want to set a limit on the number of **time-exceeded** messages sent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I've found out that I need to use access lists in order to target different types of ICMP messages. [Here](http://www.ciscopress.com/articles/article.asp?p=345618&seqNum=5) is a good explanation for this.